# new SqlConnection throws argument exception "format of the initialisation string does not conform"

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

Trying my hand at aspnet5 with a console application using the full framework. The application is going to use Dapper to make a SQL query but when instantiating the SqlConnection object I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 13.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\me\Source\ASPNET5\SysAid SLA Alarm\program.cs:line 10
```

If I remove the `\` from the server attribute then it executes fine but clearly fails because of the incorrect name and reports sql instance not found. The offending line of code looks like this:

```
using(IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection("Server=server\instance;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True"))
```

And to be complete this is my project.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "commands": {
        "ConsoleApp": "ConsoleApp"
    },
    "frameworks" : {
        "dnx451": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Data.Common": "4.0.1-beta-*",
                "Dapper": "1.50.0-beta5"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My next line of attack was to get the source for System.Data and see what's going on. Anyone spot a mistake I'm making in the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot - just using \ as a literal with `@`

```
using(IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(@"Server=server\instance;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True"))
```

Comment: yes! I'm a little too used to Visual Studio giving me lots of feedback